# App crashes without stack trace in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My app starts well but after some time it just crashes with no reasonable log report. However, I monitored the logs and discovered that the app crashes when the log below appears and I do not have enough info to debug it.

> E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe try to switch logcat output to severity "Error" and "No Filters"?

Comment: I have done that and there is still no stack trace

Comment: Samsung phones tend to have this problem, idk about other brands. Give more info like which devices or emulators you used

Comment: I have tried it with Samsung A12, Samsung S10 as well Tecno Spark 7 devices